# PowerShell: Assign an array to nested property in JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a nested Json property which I need to replace with new values. Basically I need to update one nested Json property which is an array of objects.

This is the steps I have done so far-

1. read and load the json.
2. convert the input array of stringsu(which I want to replace with) into list of objects.
3. assign the values to nested json property.
4. convert to json again and load it in a file.

But, when I assign it, the entire array is in string format in the json file. Something like this-
**"[\r\n    {\r\n        "property":**

I also tried PSObject but same results.

Steps-

```
#REPLACEMENT VALUE LOGIC
$possibleOutboundIpAddresses = az functionapp show --name xxx --resource-group yyy --output json --query possibleOutboundIpAddresses

$x=$possibleOutboundIpAddresses.Replace('"','')

#array of string with IPs
$y=$x.Split(',')

$array = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

$y.ForEach({$array.Add(@{addressRange=$_+"-"+$_})})

#this is the array format I need to replace with
$finalInputArray= $array | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 8

$jsonObject=Get-Content C:\Users\input.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonObject.p1.p2.p3=$finalInputArray

#Output
$jsonObject|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 |set-content 'C:\Users\RTH163\output.json'
```

Comment: Problem is the value I assign is being treated as a string , not an array of objects in the JSON.
Something like this-
"[\r\n    {\r\n        \"addressRange\":  \"0.0.0.0.0.\"\r\n    }]"

Instead it should be
[{"addressRange":  "13.79.246.78-13.79.246.78" }]

Comment: You're embedding a Json *string* instead of an array. Just: `$jsonObject.p1.p2.p3=@($Array)`. If you do: `Get-Content C:\Users\input.json | ConvertFrom-Json` you get a **PowerShell Object**. There is no link at all anymore to Json, meaning you might just call it `$PSObject` rather than `$jsonObject`.